# Wohin vs. worein?

Tags: preposition, relative-clause

In conversation with a native German speaker I said:

> Der Teil, den Margie am meisten hasste, war der Spalt, **wohin** sie Hausaufgaben und Prüfungpapiere stecken musste.

and she corrected me to:

> Der Teil, den Margie am meisten hasste, war der Spalt, **worein** sie Hausaufgaben und Prüfungpapiere stecken musste.

Why was this correction necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that Margie had to stick her work *into* the slot. This sense of *into* is expressed by the verb "etwas in etwas hineinstecken", especially by the prefix "hinein". The prefix "hin", on the other hand, expresses more of an idea of "in the direction of a place" or "to a place". Compare

> Er ging zum großen Haus am Ende der Straße hin.

and

> Er ging in das große Haus am Ende der Straße hinein.

In your case, the prefix of the verb is combined with "wo" into an adverb. But, as explained above, the adverb needs to be "wohinein", not "wohin". "Worein" is a shorter, more colloquial form of "wohinein".

> der Spalt, wohin sie etwas stecken musste

would translate to something like

> the slot, to where she needed to stick something

So we need

> der Spalt, wohinein sie etwas stecken musste

or

> der Spalt, worein sie etwas stecken musste

Answer (score 1):

Here, *wohin* would not imply *in*, so it definitely feels wrong, as if it would be *an den Spalt*, not *in den Spalt*.

However, I would not use *worein*. To be honest, I was unsure for a moment whether the word exists (in other contexts I would probably not have doubted it), and [looking it up](https://www.dwds.de/wb/worein) revealed that the word has become less common. I just would not use a *wo*-word here but:

> Der Teil, den Margie am meisten hasste, war der Spalt, in den sie Hausaufgaben und Prüfungpapiere stecken musste.

This is extremely natural to me. It is possible that people from other German speaking regions would disagree with that.

I am less sure about how I would formulate this as a question. I think I would go with

> Wo musste sie den Zettel hineinstecken?

I see that according to general rules on what “proper” German should be, “wohinein …” should be preferred over “wo … hinein”, but I have a hard time accepting *wohinein*, and indeed it seems to be [even rarer than *worein*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worein%2Cwohinein&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworein%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwohinein%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I put this question here just because I could find no reference to worein anywhere in German Stackexchange, and so felt it needed airing. This is good. Thank you.